# How can i make a-tree-select always expand all nodes every time in AntDV

Tags: vue.js, antd, vue-treeselect

I have two-level department linkages, at the first time when I randomly chose a department at first level selector, the second level department tree selector will be automatically generated by event `onAChange`, and expand all nodes via `tree-default-expand-all`.
when I chose another department at first level selector second time, the Second level tree selector can NOT automatically expand all nodes...

Current:
second-level tree can not expand all nodes after the first time

Expected:
second-level tree can automatically expand all nodes every time

`First level selector`

```
    <a-select
      :value="aSelectValue"
      @change="onAChange"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :allowClear="allowTreeClear"
      :disabled="departDisabled"
    >
      <a-select-option value="All">All</a-select-option>
      <a-select-option v-for="(item) in departOptions" :key="item.id" :value="item.departNumber">
         <span :style="labelStyle" :title="item.displayName">
          {{ item.departName }}
         </span>
      </a-select-option>
    </a-select>
```

`Second level tree selector`

```
      <a-tree-select
      :allowClear="allowTreeClear"
      show-search
      tree-default-expand-all
      :getPopupContainer="(node) => node.parentNode"
      style="width: 100%"
      :disabled="departDisabled"
      :dropdownStyle="{ maxHeight: '400px', overflow: 'auto' }"
      :value="departSelectValue"
      :tree-data="departTreeData"
      @change="onDepartTreeChange"
    >
    </a-tree-select>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example in CodeSandbox to debug your issue.

Comment: @zerocewl thank you for your suggestion, here is the CodeSandbox link.. just repro the issue. please feel free to take a look... https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-rwpno?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1):

As one solution you can use the `treeExpandedKeys` described in [antds tree-select api docs](https://www.antdv.com/components/tree-select/#API).

In the `onChange` call you have to update these keys depending on your treeData.

```
<a-tree-select
    ...
    :treeExpandedKeys="treeExpandedKeys"
></a-tree-select>

data() {
  return {
    departTreeData: [],
    treeExpandedKeys: [],
  ...
}

onBuChange(val) {
  ...
  _this.treeExpandedKeys = _this.departTreeData.map(data => data.key);
}
```

Here is a working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-d6fh3?file=/src/App.vue:840-915).

Comment: As only downside you have to expand the children as well. If your request is satisfied please accept the answer too.

Comment: After the test, I observed there is one more issue for `C`, that is if I selected `C`, I could not expand `c-depart-0-1`, and I could not close any nodes as well...